# Hide URL route param

Tags: angular, angular5

I have this route   `{path: 'category/:title/:id', component: CategoryPostsPageComponent},`

It shows up like this in the URL bar `http://localhost:4200/category/food/4450290839kdkjelf093ae`

Is it possible to hide the `id` property?

I tried adding `{skipLocationChange: true}` to the end of my `router.navigate()` function but then, when I reload the page, it goes back to my home page and not that same page.

Comment: If you need to hide the value, routing is probably not the best way. You could always set the ID in a service somewhere, and retrieve the value from the service instead of the URL?

Comment: That's a good suggestion, thanks! @user184994

Comment: Right, if you don't want to see something in the URL, it shouldn't be in the route.